# generating function based off class field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, python-decorators

I have a class which has fields that would all be properties with pass through getters and setters that are validated in a certain way, such that it would satisfy the following pattern:

```
import numpy as np
import typing


def validate_field(value, dtype: typing.Type):
    limits = np.iinfo(dtype)
    assert limits.min < value < limits.max, \
        "value shoule be in range: {} < {} < {}".format(limits.min, value,
                                                        limits.max)
    return value


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = c

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = validate_field(value, self._a.dtype)

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = validate_field(value, self._b.dtype)

    @c.setter
    def c(self, value):
        self._c = validate_field(value, self._c.dtype)
```

I want to eliminate having to type a separate property and setter decorator for each method.

I thought about using properties manually via

```
self._a = a
def set_a(self, value):
    self._a = validate_field(value, self._a.dtype)
self.a = property(lambda self: self._a, set_a)
...
```

However, it seemed I would still have to manually define a function that accessed the required member for both setter and getter, so I wasn't really saving much work.

If there was a way to automatically generate such functions via naming the parameter e.g.:

```
def generate_function(self, parameter)
    def temp(self, value):
        self.parameter = validate_field(value, self.parameter.dtype)
    return temp
```

then I wouldn't have any issues, but right now I don't see how to accomplish this.

Is there a way for me to generate these functions with a single decorator per field or automated function based property generation in `__init__`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getattr()` and `setattr()`, or direct dictionary access via `self.__dict__`, to parametrize the attribute name:

```
def validated_property(name):
    def getter(self):
        return getattr(self, name)

    def setter(self, value):
        dtype = getter(self).dtype
        setattr(self, name, validate_field(value, dtype))

    return property(getter, setter)
```

then use this as

```
class Foo:
    # ...

    a = validated_property('_a')
    b = validated_property('_b')
    c = validated_property('_c')
```

etc.

If you are using Python 3.6 or newer, you can avoid having to repeat the attribute name and generate one from the name for the property (by prefixing it with `_`, for example), by [implementing your own descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), which is passed the name under which it is being assigned to a class via the [`descriptor.__set_name__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__):

```
class ValidatedProperty:
    _name = None

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return getattr(instance, self._name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        dtype = self.__get__(instance, type(instance)).dtype
        setattr(instance, self._name, validate_field(value, dtype))
```

then use this like this:

```
class Foo:
    # ...

    a = ValidatedProperty()
    b = ValidatedProperty()
    c = ValidatedProperty()
```

Comment: You could also use `getter(self).dtype` there. And if OP is feeling adventurous, they can use `a, b, c = [validated_property(name) for name in sorcery.assigned_names()]`.

Comment: @AlexHall: Just use a generator expression and dispense with the list, if you are going to generate the names.